# How can I avoid django channels runtime errors when using signals?

Tags: python-asyncio, django-channels

I have a django service (say `'brisbane'`) that is pushing updates to client browsers when database models are saved using channels and signals thus:

```
def invalidated_serialized_model_receiver(self, sender, **kwargs):
    ...
    async_to_sync(get_channel_layer().group_send)(name, update)
```

This works and gives nice real time updates.

`'brisbane'` now needs to interact with another service (same code) `'sydney'` so that it can be similarly updated in real time with respect to changes in `sydney's` data. This uses a consumer running in another process looking something like this:

```
async def remote_site_consume(site):
    socket_url = site.urn(protocol='ws', resource_name='/ws/watch/')
    async with websockets.connect(socket_url) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(json.dumps({'type': 'watch_messages'}))
        ...
        async for event in websocket:
            event = json.loads(event)
            await get_event_handler(event)(site, websocket, event)
```

The signal may get sent legitimately from within the event handler which is where the problem occurs. When this happens, it throws a RuntimeError

> 'You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop
>   - just await the async function directly.'

I can't just use await though because the signal is sent from threads with no event loop as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying with this replacement for async_to_sync which seems to work in local tests at least:

```
def invalidated_serialized_model_receiver(self, sender, **kwargs):
    ...
    create_or_use_loop(self.channel_layer.group_send(name, update))


def create_or_use_loop(awaitable):
    try:
        event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    except RuntimeError:
        event_loop = None

    if event_loop and event_loop.is_running():
        event_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(event_loop.create_task, awaitable)
    else:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        try:
            loop.run_until_complete(awaitable)
        finally:
            loop.close()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(event_loop)
```

This feels very clunky though.